# Fastest way of solving system of linear equation with huge matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, linear-equation

My system of linear equation is represented in the form `AX = B`. In order to find `X`, `X = inverse(A) * B`.

There are quite a number of libraries such as `numpy.linalg.solve`, `numpy.linalg.lstsq` or `numpy.linalg.inv` to solve for X. However, with the size of `A = 20000 * 20000, the computational time using any of the libraries listed above is huge.

With that said, working on a huge dataset (`size(A) = 20000*20000` and `size(B) = 20000 * 1`) with my psuedocode being,

```
X = numpy.linalg.inv(A)*B)
```

`X` will be iterated over 25000 times so time is very crutial.

Is there a faster way of solving the linear equation?

Comment: Have you considered numerical methods? Maybe gradient-descent (with an acceptable error-margin)

Comment: Does `A` have any special properties that the solver could use?

Comment: @hpaulj. A is a covariance Matrix. It has no other special property

Comment: if it's covariance matrix, isn't it symmetric?

Comment: @Botond, yes it is symmetric

Comment: @user2554925 I think you can gain some there, inverting a symmetric matrix should be faster. Maybe not orders of magnitude faster, but faster if you use a corresponding algorithm.

Comment: Another thing: if A, B and X don't change much in between iterations (for example they change during a dt timestep only, by a small amount) you may exploit that to speed up solutions. A gradient descent (or equivalent) will be fast because you're already close to the solution from the previous iteration.